Pandas csv_read interprets empty values as row headers
let's say I have a data like:
parameter1 parameter2  2010 2011 2012
A          B           foo  foo  foo
           C           foo  foo  foo
           D           foo  foo  foo
M          N           bar  bar  bar
           O           bar  bar  bar

which exported to CSV would look something like this:
parameter1,parameter2,2010,2011,2012
A,B,foo,foo,foo
,C,foo,foo,foo
,D,foo,foo,foo
M,N,bar,bar,bar
,O,bar,bar,bar

when I try to read the csv like:
pd.read_csv("file.csv", index_col=[0,1])

I however get:
            2010  2011  2012
A      B    foo   foo   foo
NaN    C    foo   foo   foo
       D    foo   foo   foo
M      N    bar   bar   bar
NaN    O    bar   bar   bar

Is there a way to make Pandas understand that if the value haven't been provided for a row Index as CSV it should treat it like the indexed hasn't changed, instead of giving it NaN index?
What I would expect instead after reading csv:
            2010  2011  2012
A      B    foo   foo   foo
       C    foo   foo   foo
       D    foo   foo   foo
M      N    bar   bar   bar
       O    bar   bar   bar


You can use ffill after reading the file to fill the NaN values in the relevant columns. For example,
df[['parameter1', 'parameter2']] = df[['parameter1', 'parameter2']].ffill()
df.set_index(['parameter1', 'parameter2'], inplace=True)
df

Output:

>                           2010 2011 2012
>     parameter1 parameter2               
>     A          B           foo  foo  foo
>                C           foo  foo  foo
>                D           foo  foo  foo
>     M          N           bar  bar  bar
>                O           bar  bar  bar



KeyError: "None of [Index(['parameter1', 'parameter2'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]", (when I try to use ffill()

If your column list includes "parameter1", and "parameter2", it should work correctly.

edit: got it, just need to read without index_col specified

Code
tmp = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
idx = [0, 1] # integer location you tried to pass to index_col
cols = tmp.iloc[:, idx].columns.tolist()
tmp[cols] = tmp[cols].ffill()
df = tmp.set_index(cols)

df:
                      2010 2011 2012
parameter1 parameter2               
A          B           foo  foo  foo
           C           foo  foo  foo
           D           foo  foo  foo
M          N           bar  bar  bar
           O           bar  bar  bar

